# Gimp ctrl A selection change my font into weird symbols

Tags: fonts, gimp

A very weird bug, but I'm using gimp 2.10.18, on ubuntu 20.04. I'm working on old documents from ubuntu 16.04, but when I select all the text, using ctrl A ou with the mouse, all my text change font and become weird greek symbols.

It is very annoying and I hope someone could work on that for an update.

Comment: Are you sure your current *focal* system has all fonts your *xenial* system had? or at least all those used by the `gimp` file you're working on.

Comment: How do you check that, I did install some font from windows, like georgia, I don't know it is may had mess up the genuine font. But I'm getting a hard time, it happens often and randomly, it changes to Standard Symbols PS font. CTRL Z don't even work to get back to Georgia.

Comment: I manage to get over it by opening a .txt file, coy and paste, erase layer and crate a new. It looks like a problem between old and new version of gimp.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Fedora 32, installed from rpms/dnf.

One workaround is not to mark text across line breaks. So if I mark text (either by mouse or by holding shift and using keys) within one line, conversion/loss of font does not happen. Otherwise it reverts it to some strange font (and CTRL-A does the same as there are multiple lines).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some bug reports for it:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/3104
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/7262 marked as a duplicate of the above

Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150676/gimp-text-changes-when-editing-it

I observed this on Ubuntu 22.10, GIMP 2.10.32 when opening some .xcf files created on an older GIMP version (don't remember which). It might also only affect text fields that contain non-ASCII character, but not 100% sure about that.